# How to find divisors of number on specified interval?

Tags: c++, while-loop, numbers

I want to write a simple progam using WHILE loop, with which you could get all divisors of the number which you put in.

For example you want all divisors of number 30, which are: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30. 
Now you want program to display only numbers on interval (for example) from 5 - 10, which are 5, 6 and 10.

What i tried so far is getting all those divisors using FOR sentence, but without intervals, so I am stucked and don't know how could make it also in WHILE loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int input_number;

cin >> input_number;
cout << "All numbers are " << input_number << endl;

for (int i = 1; i <= input_number; i++) {
    if (input_number % i == 0) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help in addition.

Comment: Add another if statement and check if `i` is in the range of the filter.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, I figured that out too, but it's the problem i don't know how to remake whole thing to while loop.

Comment: Well what have you tried?  I while loop and a for loop are basically the same you just have to handle the loop variables yourself.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't even know how to start with it. I know what while loop looks like, but don't know what to take for condition and what for statement.

Comment: a for loop doesn't have to go from **1** to **input_number** change them with local variables and the condition for your for/while loop will come automatically

Comment: @A.B Thank you, I managed the whole for loop now, just need to "translate" it now to while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this problem in a `while` loop is probably not as simple (or brute-force) as solving it in a `for` loop.

Consider this rendition of the loop using `while`:

```cpp
int input_number;

std::cin >> input_number;

int i = 1; //Start trying to divide the input number by 1
int limit = input_number; //Termination condition for the loop
while(i < limit) {
  if(input_number % i == 0) { //If divisible by i, both i and input_number/i are factors
    std::cout << i << " " << input_number / i << " ";
  }
  ++i; //Try dividing by the next integer
  /*Set the limit to our latest input_number/i so we don't get duplicate 
    results (e.g. (5, 6) and (6, 5) for input_number = 30)*/
  limit = input_number / i;
}
```

For `input_number = 30`, this loop only runs for 5 iterations, while the `for` loop version runs for 30 iterations.

**Bottom Line**

`for` loops and `while` loops are interchangeable, but approaching a problem using a `for` loop might bring you to a different solution faster than approaching the problem with a `while` loop and vice versa as they help you think about the problem from different perspectives.

**Extra Information**

The `for` loop version allows for certain optimization techniques such as parallel accumulators, which are not possible in the `while` loop version as each iteration depends on the previous.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this as a `while` loop? `for` is definitely the correct choice of loop here. Checking *all* divisors is done quite clearly via:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= input_number; i++) { ... }
```

If you want to add a narrower window to that, you can just change the bounds of the loop:

```
for (int i = lower_bound; i <= upper_bound; i++) { ... }
```

---

Turning that into a `while` loop would just involve unwrapping those statements into:

```
int i = lower_bound;
while (i <= upper_bound) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

But this is more error-prone - if you had a `continue` in your loop body, `i` would not get incremented.

Comment: Well I wanted to make that program using for and while loop, because I am new at programming and wanted to see the diference in code, but I am stucked with translating from     for to    while lopp.